# Java: Properties file as JSON in Android

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, properties-file

On the server I have a .properties file with the following structure

```
foo.0.a = foo0A
foo.0.b = foo0B
foo.1.a = foo1A
foo.1.b = foo1B
...

bar.0.a = bar0a
bar.0.b = bar0b
...
```

I'm using Volley to fetch the file from the server as JSONObject but the output is being returned in the following form

```
"properties": [
    {
        "key": "foo.0.a",
        "type": "text/plain",
        "value": "foo0A"
    },
    {
        "key": "bar.0.a",
        "type": "text/plain",
        "value": "bar0a"
    },
]
```

This is not the format I'm looking for, and I think it is not convenient anyway.
The wanted format is something like this:

```
{
   "foo": [
      {
         "id": 0,
         "a": "foo0a",
         "b": "foo0b"
      }, ...
   ]
   "bar": [
      {
         "id": 0,
         "a": "bar0a",
         "b": "bar0b"
      }, ...
   ]
}
```

My question: Should the properties' structure be changed? Or this can be solved by some code on the client side? If it should be changed, what is the best structure?

Comment: If you can change the file to anything you want, just store it as json.

Comment: @nasch the properties file must be in a Java properties file format.

Comment: I would probably just transform the json into the format you want on the client side manually.

Comment: @nasch I will try something like this http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/java/javaConfig.html